# Combining non-blocking and blocking calls and returning the results in Spring Webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, nonblocking, spring-reactive

I am using Spring Webflux along with Spring boot 2 and my scenario goes like this:

### Controller

```
@GetMapping(path="/products")
public List<Products> getProducts(){
 return serviceObj.getProducts();
}
```

### Service Class

```
public List<Products> getProducts(){
List<Products> products = null;
  //Call 1 -> to repository class method returning Flux<Products>
repositoryObj.getProductsFlux();
  //Call 2 -> To repository class method returning List<Products>
repositoryObj.getProductsNormal();
  //Concat results from Call 1 & Call 2 and return List<Products>
return products;
}
```

How can I concatenate results from a Flux & normal list of products before returning?
Is it possible without having a Reactive Controller ?

P.S. I don't want to call .block() and CompleteableFuture on the results obtained from Call 1

Comment: There is no way to get the Future without blocking. You have to use `.block()` to get the result. I have been working on Webflux for a year now, so I would say never mix blocking and non-blocking, a seriously bad design. In this case, you should revise your concepts on the Reactor core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this without `.block()` way if you want to return `List<Products>` from that method.

You should rather merge the results and return `Flux<Products>` from this method to keep the reactive approach. You can use [`mergeWith`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#mergeWith-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-) or [`concatWith`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concatWithValues-T...-)

**Example:**

```
public Flux<Products> getProducts(){
    List<Products> productsNonFlux = repositoryObj.getProductsNormal();
    Flux<Products> productsFlux = repositoryObj.getProductsFlux();
    return productsFlux.mergeWith(Flux.fromIterable(productsNonFlux));
}
```

**IMPORTANT!**

Keep in mind that if your `repositoryObj.getProductsNormal()` is using JDBC then this call will block the thread pool.

In such case take a look on:
[Execute blocking JDBC call in Spring Webflux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54864088/execute-blocking-jdbc-call-in-spring-webflux)